# React Hook "useState" is called in function "nav" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
import {useState} from 'react'

const nav = () => {
  const [activeNav, setActiveNav] = useState('#')
}
```

I was trying to build a nav bar.
and I am getting this error I don't know why

```
React Hook "useState" is called in function "nav" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function. React component names must start with an uppercase letter. React Hook names must start with the word "use"  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically it seems like one or both of the following is the cause of your issue:

1. `nav` is not a valid React component. React components are capitalized.
2. `nav` might not be rendered as a React component.

Rename to `Nav` so it's at least named correctly.

```
import {useState} from 'react'

const Nav = () => {
  const [activeNav, setActiveNav] = useState('#');

  ...

  return (
    // return valid JSX
  );
}
```

Render `Nav` as a React component:

- Valid

  ```
   <Nav />
  ```
- Invalid

  ```
   {Nav()}
  ```

Answer (score -1):

OK here is what you can do, rename the nav function to Nav and it's export default nav to export default Nav at the end of the function this should solve your problem and stop your errors and build your website

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).